# Error in MultiMain could not resolve directory webpack issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server

I know this issue is prevalent but the best part is it differs from person to person

[image: While running webpack server]

In my case my folder structure is 
[image: Folder Structure]

My files:
Webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
const Files = {
input: path.resolve(__dirname,'src/app'),
output: path.resolve(__dirname,'output')
}
console.log(Files.input);
var config = {
entry: Files.input,
output: {
    path: Files.output,
    filename: 'index.js',
},
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 9009
},
resolve: { modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'], extensions: ['','.js','.jsx'] },
stats: {
    colors: true,
    modules: true,
    reasons: true,
    errorDetails: true
},
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
    }]
}
}

module.exports = config;
```

Package.json

```
{
"name": "reactapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "output/index.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
},
"author": "batman",
"license": "AMIGOS",
"dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
}
}
```

I have kept package.json in my app folder too with dummy json `{"name":"hello"}`
as part of suggestion from one of developer. I have tried all the possible scenarios which are in my vicinity but in vain.
Please shed some light on this.

Update:
with change of folder from !bharath to bharath error reduced to 1.

Comment: You have your input as `path.resolve(__dirname,'src/app/level2'),` but I don't see a `level2.js` anywhere in the `app` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Files = {
  // you need to specify the file name as well as webpack entry
  input: path.resolve(__dirname,'src/app/main.js'), 
  output: path.resolve(__dirname,'output')
}
```